# Comparing models when their performance may depend on a continuous variable

Tags: aic, model-comparison

I am interested in using an information-theoretic approach (likely AIC) to compare the fit of several models to a dependent variable `X`. M<sub>1</sub> may take the form `X~A+B+C` and M<sub>2</sub> may take the form `X~D+E`.

However, I suspect that the performance of these models may depend on continuous variable `F`. e.g. for low values of `F`, M<sub>1</sub> performs best; but for high values of `F`, M<sub>2</sub> performs best.

My first thought was to partition the data into two sets corresponding to high and low values of `F`, then compare the models on each subset of the data. But I have several worries about this approach including that I may lose some information in converting a continuous variable into a discrete one.

Is it possible to (1) test if model performance is dependent on some variable and (2) compare models when observations for different values of `F` may follow different trends without discretizing `F`? If either is possible, what is the recommended approach?